# Закрытие клавиатуры при переходе на другой экран

Tags: java, android

У меня есть `Activity` в котором есть текстовое поля для ввода текста, соответственно используется клавиатура и при закрытии окна, клиатура не закрывается.

**Вопрос:** как можно закрывать клавиатуру когда я покидаю текущий экран?

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.
    View view =getCurrentFocus();
    //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
    if (view == null) {
        view = new View(this);
    }
    if (imm != null) {
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: Закрывайте клавиатуру при открытии нового окна.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант 1: В AndroidManifest.xml добавить параметр для новой Activity:

```
<activity 
...
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

Вариант 2: использовать другой метод у InputMethodManager:

```
imm.toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```